# Kafka failover across regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, failover, confluent-platform

If we have a Kafka cluster with replication factor turned on but all brokers in the same region - how do we prevent from a case **if a whole region goes down**?

Is it possible to have some of the brokers in e.g. East Region and some of them in West Region?

How much latency affects this?

If that is not recommended - what is the best solution to have a failover in case a whole region goes down?

If we would have 2 clusters all the time - what are best practices for replication and/or Producer writing to both cluster at the same time same messages?

Comment: My experience with Kafka is a couple of versions out of date so I'm not putting this as an answer. At the time I was using it, general consensus was that cross-region latency would be excessive (indeed, a lot of people considered cross-AZ latency unacceptable, but I didn't see any problems with a 5-node cluster). So to implement a fallback you could feed from one cluster to another.